# Dual Boot Mac - Ubuntu booting into a black screen before GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, mac

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro in a dual boot setup managed with reFIND.

It worked great for a couple of days. But last night I forgot to put it on charging/switch off the computer. It shut down by discharging while on Ubuntu. Now when I start up my laptop, it shows the reFind screen. I pick Ubuntu. After that I get a purple screen for 5 seconds after which the screen turns black and seems to be off.

The laptop is not powered off though, since it is still heating. I need to force shutdown my laptop using the power button.

Basically, I am not even able to get the GRUB menu. What do I do? How can I repair my dual boot Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

GRUB isn't linked to Ubuntu booting as far as i know. So you should at least get to he Grub interface.
Well I've really not got that much of an expertise on Mac OSs. It's probably because your graphic card. Assuming you can at least get to the GRUB menu before it goes completely black, press F6 adn you should get booted into a different screen with different options, choose `nomodeset`. In some cases it might not show it as an option so just add manually `nomodeset quiet splash`, and it should get you booted on a GUI. Basically what it does it tells kernel to not to load the video drivers and use the BIOS instead. For adding the command in the GRUB it's keys varies so just look at the bottom of the GRUB and it should give you the key to add or edit a command.
It should get you into a graphical environment once you boot with the new option you added.See if this works out for you

If you can't even access the GRUB menu it might be the problem of rEFInd so you may want to reinstall that.

Comment: I am able to access rEFInd, but never reach the GRUB. I see a purple screen on clicking 'Boot Ubuntu' and then immediately after, a black screen. 

I have no where to enter the nomodeset. Also, I have been using the Ubuntu for 2 days with no graphics problem. Can this error still occur?

Comment: So I get now what is the problem. Next time it happens just turn off the computer and press the power button 5 times and that should do the trick.